# Extremal density of a graph without a non-backtracking $2k$-cycle

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, cycles

The current best bound for the maximum possible density of an $n$-node graph with girth (shortest cycle length) $>2k$ is of the form
$$ex(n \ \mid \ C_{\le 2k}) = O(n^{1 + 1/k}),$$
while the current best bound for the maximum possible density of a graph without a $2k$-cycle is of the form
$$ex(n \ \mid C_{2k}) = O(k \cdot n^{1 + 1/k}).$$
[Edit: this bound is actually wrong, see accepted answer below.]
An "intermediate" question is the maximum possible density of a graph without a "non-backtracking $2k$-cycle," which we define as a circularly-ordered sequence of $2k$ nodes in which adjacent nodes are connected by an edge and there is no continuous subsequence of the form $(u, v, u)$.  It is not hard to see that this function $ex(n \ \mid \ C^{\not \leftarrow}_{2k})$ lies between the above two, but:

> 1. Is $ex(n \ \mid \ C^{\not \leftarrow}_{2k})$ known to be asymptotically equivalent to either of these two functions?
> 2. (If not) is any upper bound on $ex(n \ \mid \ C^{\not \leftarrow}_{2k})$ known that is asymptotically better than $O(k \cdot n^{1 + 1/k})$?

Comment: Could you remind us what the density of a graph is?

Comment: @fedja Here, I mean it just as the number of edges in the graph, $|E|$ in $G = (V, E)$.

Comment: For those curious about the two quoted bounds (as I was), there is a lot of information in this survey of Füredi and Simonovits http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.5167

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best bounds on $ex(n, C^{\not \leftarrow}_{2k})$ and on $ex(n, C_{2k})$ that we can prove with the current techniques are going to be basically same. Below I explain why.

First, contrary to what the question states the best known bound on the number of edges in $C_{2k}$-free graphs is $O(\sqrt{k}\log k\cdot n^{1+1/k})$, as proved in [a paper of Jiang and myself](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.1601).

In the appendix of that paper, we also show that this bound is almost the best one can obtain without improving the bound on $ex(n,C_{\leq 2k})$ itself. That construction also works for non-backtracking cycles. For completeness, I review the construction below.

For simplicity assume that $k$ is even. Consider bipartite version of the girth problem. Namely, we seek a $C_{\leq 2k}$-free bipartite graph whose parts have size $m$ and $n$. The same argument as in non-bipartite case shows that the number of edges in this case is at most $cn^{1/k}(mn)^{1/2}$ if $k$ is even. Let $m=n/k$ and suppose that this bound is tight, i.e., there is $C_{\leq 2k}$-free bipartite graph with parts $n/k$ and $n$ with $Ck^{-1/2}n^{1+1/k}$ edges. Replace each vertex in the smaller part by an independent set of size $k$ to get a graph $G$ with $Ck^{1/2}n^{1+1/k}$ edges. This graph contains no $C^{\not \leftarrow}_{2k}$ as the vertices of $C^{\not \leftarrow}_{2k}$ would induce a cycle length at most $2k$ in the original graph.

So, apart from the $\log k$ factor, no improvement is going to happen until we improve on the basic girth argument.

Comment: That's a great result, sorry I hadn't found it earlier.  Congrats!

Answer (score 0):

My upper bound is indeed correct and answers the question you wrote here (at least the upper-bound part), although my previous analysis was lacking in that it needed to account for floors and ceilings as we are dealing with integers. More precisely, it holds if $k$ is defined to be the largest integer such that the length of the smallest cycle is **greater than** $2k$ (as stated in your original question). Now, if $k$ were instead defined as the largest integer such that the length of the smallest cycle is **at least** (as opposed to strictly greater than) $2k$, it is indeed a different story. Is this what was really meant?

Let $D$ be such that $G$ has $(D+1)n$ edges where $n$ is the number of vertices. Then the average degree $D'$ of each vertex in $G$ is $2D+2$. You can use the link I posted to show that, letting $k' = \lfloor \frac{\log n}{\log(D)} \rfloor$, the length of the smallest cycle is no more than $2k'+2$, and is in fact no more than $2k'+1$ if $k'$ turns out to be exactly $\frac{\log n}{\log(D)}$.

So let $k$ be the largest integer such that the length of the smallest cycle is **greater than** $2k$. Then in either case $k$ must be no greater than $k'$ defined in the paragraph above. Thus, $k$ must satisfy $k \leq \frac{\log n}{\log(D)}$ (no ceiling functions needed) which implies that $\log(D)$ must satisfy
$\log(D) \leq \frac{\log n}{k}$, which implies that $D$ must satisfy $D \leq n^{\frac{1}{k}}$, which implies that $D+1$ must satisfy $D+1\leq n^{\frac{1}{k}}+1$. So the average degree $D'$ of $G$ must satisfy $D'\leq 2n^{\frac{1}{k}}+2$.

Now, let $k$ be the largest integer such that the length of the smallest cycle is **at least** (as opposed to strictly greater than) $2k$. There my analysis (in the link I posted) guarantees only the slightly weaker inequality of $k \leq \lceil \frac{\log n}{\log(D)}\rceil$, which (for a range of values of $k$ relative to $n$) would allow $\log(D) -\frac{\log n}{k}$ to be large enough to allow $D$ to be much larger than $\theta(n^{\frac{1}{k}})$ and even $\theta(kn^{\frac{1}{k}})$.

Comment: Yes, this upper bound is right and well known -- it is called the "Moore Bounds."  You may be misreading the OP, my question was not about how to prove these bounds or whether they are tight.  My question is about whether this analysis can be extended to a graph without a non-backtracking cycle of length exactly $2k$.  The usual proof of the Moore bound (more or less what you linked in the other answer) does not seem to imply this directly.

Comment: Yes looking back now I do think I misread. I wish I had something more useful for your question.